# How to successfully mock and catch an error using Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I've been stuck trying to create a specific test for a few days now, and would appreciate any insight into what I may be doing wrong.

I am trying to mock out the Array filter function to throw an error.

userHelper.js

```
//filter users by email ending
const filterUsersByEmailDomain = (usersArray, emailEnding) => {
    try {
        let bizUsers = usersArray.filter(user => {
            return user.email.endsWith(emailEnding);
        });
        return bizUsers;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('error filtering users. Throwing error.');
        throw err;
    }
}
```

userHelper.test.js:

```
it('should throw', () => {
        const user1 = {id: 1, email: 'tyler@tyler.com'};
        const user2 = {id: 2, email: 'tevin@tevin.biz'};
        const userArray = [user1, user2];
        const domainEnding = '.biz';

        Array.prototype.filter = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {throw new Error()});

        expect(() => {usersHelper.filterUsersByEmailDomain(userArray, domainEnding)}).toThrow();
    });
```

From what I can tell, the error is being thrown, but isn't successfully being caught. I've also tried making the called to usersHelper.filterUsersByEmailDomain() within a try catch block as i have seen others do, but was also unsuccessful. Thanks in advance!

Edit: 
Here is the error I receive when running this test setup locally in my project.

```
  ● Testing the usersHelper module › should throw



      56 |         const domainEnding = '.biz';
      57 | 
    > 58 |         Array.prototype.filter = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {throw new Error()});
         |                                                                            ^
      59 | 
      60 |         expect(() => {usersHelper.filterUsersByEmailDomain(userArray, domainEnding)}).toThrow();
      61 |     });

      at Array.filter.jest.fn.mockImplementation (utils/__tests__/usersHelper.test.js:58:76)
      at _objectSpread (node_modules/expect/build/index.js:60:46)
      at Object.throwingMatcher [as toThrow] (node_modules/expect/build/index.js:264:19)
      at Object.toThrow (utils/__tests__/usersHelper.test.js:60:87)

(node:32672) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error
(node:32672) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .c
atch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:32672) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: I would suggest that you give `spyOn` a try like in `const spy = jest.spyOn(userArray, 'filter').mockImplementation(() => throw new Error())`. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname

Comment: I've setup the test https://repl.it/repls/MedicalIntelligentTriangles and it seems to be working fine

Comment: @Teneff hmmm that is strange. The repl.it example you posted above seems to work for me as well. However, I still get an error when I run this test locally :( I have edited the post to include the error I am getting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array.prototype.filter` is a very low-level function and mocking it to throw an error can cause your tests to not run properly.

Take this simple test:

```
it('should throw', () => {
  expect(() => { throw new Error() }).toThrow();  // Success!
});
```

...which works fine...

...but mock `Array.prototype.filter` to throw an error and it fails:

```
it('should throw', () => {
  Array.prototype.filter = jest.fn(() => { throw new Error() });
  expect(() => { throw new Error() }).toThrow();  // Fail!
});
```

---

Instead, just mock `filter` on the array itself:

```
it('should throw', () => {
  const user1 = { id: 1, email: 'tyler@tyler.com' };
  const user2 = { id: 2, email: 'tevin@tevin.biz' };
  const userArray = [user1, user2];
  const domainEnding = '.biz';

  userArray.filter = () => { throw new Error() };  // <= mock filter on userArray

  expect(() => { usersHelper.filterUsersByEmailDomain(userArray, domainEnding) }).toThrow();  // Success!
});
```

JavaScript looks for a property on the object itself before checking its prototype so the mock `filter` on `userArray` gets called in `filterUsersByEmailDomain` and the test passes as expected.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! Great explanation. Only thing I tweaked was the mocking of the function. `userArray.filter = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {throw new Error()});`

Answer (score 1):

You want to put your `toThrow()` before the execution of the tested function, in Jest 'toX' means that it must be setup beforehand e.g: `toBeCalled()`. This is why `toHaveBeenCalled()` exists, as this form allows the assertion to happen after the code has run.